# Pyplot Interactive Zooming

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to display an image that is zoomed in when first shown, but still has the ability to zoom out to the full scale using the interactive "Reset original view" button in the figure toolbar. Cropping is completely unacceptable. Using `plt.axis([x0, x1, y0, y1])` does allow panning but the interactive window will not reset to full scale.

Is there a way to trigger the plot to zoom or solve this issue another way?

Comment: This will involve poking at the history stack buried in the tool bar. See the attribute `toolbar._views`.  Be aware anything you make to work using this will involve touching the internals of mpl and can be broken at any time.  There is an effort to re-factor the tools bars to make this more sane, see https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/wiki/Mep22

Comment: and to be clear, you want to _programtically_ zoom, not interactively.

Comment: @tcaswell Yes, it should be programmatic. I was hoping there was just some command like "zoom_window" or something but I suppose that's not the case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A way to do this is:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.imshow(np.random.rand(20, 20)
fig.canvas.toolbar.push_current()  # save the 'un zoomed' view to stack
ax.set_xlim([5, 10])
ax.set_ylim([5, 10])
fig.canvas.toolbar.push_current()  # save 'zoomed' view to stack
```

I am not sure how private `push_current` is considered and as I said in the comments this is being refactored for 1.5 (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/wiki/Mep22).

See https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/backend_bases.py#L2600 for how pan/zoom are implemented. The reason there isn't a 'zoom_window' command is for static images, you just use `set_*lim`.